# How can I host my Ruby on Rails application - no hosting providers offer SQLite3 database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm really new at Ruby on Rails development. I'm reading Head First Rails and it says that Rails uses SQLite3 as its database system.

How exactly would I go about uploading my website/application so the world can use it?

Comment: You don't have to use SQLlite3 with Rails. You can use Mysql, Postgres and even Oracle if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses sqlite3 by default, though you can edit your `database.yml` file to use a different adaptor (mysql, postgres, etc.) if you'd like. It's not recommended to deploy to production using sqlite3 as your database due to performance issues, though small apps would be ok.

Comment: As Heroku rewrites the `config/database.yml` file in the generated slug, I think you'll find Heroku deploys of Rails apps will always use PostgreSQL.

Comment: You're right and I edited the response. I was not aware that Rails apps were forced to use postgres at heroku. How tragic. I've had great success there with Sinatra/Rack apps however.

Comment: Other options for Heroku db - use Amazon RDS (mysql), but this comes at an additional cost - http://docs.heroku.com/amazon_rds (seems postgres is a better choice unless you have some mysql specific needs?)
or mongodb if you want to go noSQL http://docs.heroku.com/mongohq

Comment: That's much more than I was aware of. Thanks for that. I'm quite surprised there isn't a simple way for a Rails app to use a sqlite db when so much else is possible. You could write your own custom initialization I guess, but yuck.